# Executing .done() function for Ajax request resent in .ajaxError()

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have a global `ajaxError()` function for a web app. The web app uses Cookie auth with Azure AD OpenIdConnect. I'm trying to handle a case when the cookie expires before an ajax request to my API is made. If the cookie has expired the API will return a 302 response to the Microsoft login, which then attempts to re-auth the user but fails due to CORS. When this happens I append an iframe to the page with a src set to a URL in my app that will reauth the user and return updated cookies.

I am re-sending the ajax request like this:

```
$(document).ajaxError(function (event, request, settings, thrownError) {
        if (/* CORS error */) {
            var iframe = document.createElement("iframe");
            iframe.style.display = "none";
            iframe.src = reAuthUri;
            document.body.appendChild(iframe);

            // Re-send request.
            $.ajax(settings);
        }
    });
```

This does work, it re-sends the request with the updated cookies and succeeds, but my `.done()` callback is never fired. Example:

```
$.ajax({
  type: "GET",
  url: "/api/things/"
}).done(result => doSomething());
```

The `doSomething()` is not called. If I change the ajax request to use `success` instead of `done()`, then it works:

```
$.ajax({
  type: "GET",
  url: "/api/things/",
  success: result => doSomething()
});
```

However, since `.done()` is the preferred way of handling ajax callbacks now, every ajax request in the app is written using it instead of the old `success` property. So, is there somehow a way to get the `.done()` action for a request to be called when re-sending the request in `.ajaxError()`?

Comment: which version of jQuery used?

Comment: @MedetTleukabiluly v3.3.1.

Comment: `request` is the `jqXHR` object. You could *try* doing `$.ajax(settings).done(request.done)` and see if it works. I doubt it, but you never know...

Comment: Gave it a shot. `request.done` is something different and executing it as a callback does nothing.

Answer (score 3):

You are never actually re-sending your ajax request, you are sending a new one with the exact same setting as the first one. However, since the `$.ajax` function returns a `Deferred` object, which at this state is rejected, it is not possible to get its `done` callback.

You need to create a new `done` callback for when you are resending your "new" ajax request, or use the `success` attribute in the setting, since it's passed to the `ajaxError` function.

You could also send your `done` callback with your setting and retrieve it in the `ajaxError` function. Take note that the `doneFunction` is not a standard jQuery ajax parameter -- I've added it.

```js
// THE GLOBAL CODE 
$(document).ajaxError(function (event, request, settings, thrownError) {
  let originalDoneCallback = settings.doneFunction;
  // here we are calling directly the done attribute to prove it is the same as before.
  originalDoneCallback()
  // Since it's a function, you could use it as so. 
  //$.ajax(settings).done(originalDoneCallback);
});



// THE LOCAL CODE 
// we are using this object to prevent having to code our done function twice.
let ajaxSettings =  {
  doneFunction: function() {
    console.log('new done!')
  }
};


$.ajax('https://test.test',ajaxSettings).done(ajaxSettings.doneFunction);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Unfortunately I'm attempting to use this globally, so I can't define the `.done()` callback for the new request without knowing what it was for the original one. I may have to abandon this approach.

Comment: @Valuator I have edited my answer according to that.